# Parsing multi-document YAML doesn't give any successful result

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, yaml

I have a long multi-document YAML that needs to be parsed, let me show you some fragments of what it looks like:

```
---
message: Object has changed  to concrete class.
date: 2022-11-30T07:33:07.992955008Z
reponame: myRepo
---
message: Type  has been created.
date: 2022-11-30T07:33:07.992956372Z
reponame: myRepo
---
message: Constant has been created.
date: 2022-11-30T07:33:07.992956372Z
reponame: myRepo
```

And this one needs to be converted to the array of JS-objects / JSON.
I have tried several libraries, but only was supporting multi-documents sources to be parsed ( library calls `yaml` ), but the problem is - it's parsing function returning an array of Document type of objects (attached picture is an example what I am getting as a result, sorry I can't paste the code - sandbox is not giving such opportunity), which is not good for me.

Is there any way to turn this yaml into array of objects?

[image]

Comment: @DiegoD this library doesnt support multi-document sources.

Comment: I removed the previous suggestion. I did not consider the multipart aspect to be blocking. Anyway what's wrong with the Document objects you obtain from the parsing? It's the Document type that you don't like or the fact that you need those object to be merged?

Comment: @DiegoD I don't know how to operate that to tell the truth, I just need an array of regular objects as an output

Comment: you may try to use that yaml library suggested before js-yaml and do `const documents = []; documents.push(yaml.parse(yamlString));` then since I expect those documents to be array of objects having those 3 props (message, date, reponame), you can just join all those arrays in one. Probably to get that array for each document you may need `Object.values(documents[i])`

Comment: @DiegoD I figured out what to do. You can check the answer. Thanks for your desire to help out

Comment: you went much further than I could suggest. I was trying to give advice on something that I never used myself and wasn't aware of its full capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Have found the proper way. This way you can get the resulted array as a JSON:

```
const yaml = require("yaml");

const data = yaml.parseAllDocuments("./path/to/yamlFile");
const res = data.map((item)=>item.toJS());
```